# Not able to access the values from request-promise response

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I have a below code which is giving me response but when i try to access properties of the response, i am getting 'undefined'

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const option= {
method: 'GET',
uri: 'urihere',
qs: {
    q: 'Mark'
},
json: true,
resolveWithFullResponse: true,
headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'requestXYZPromise',
    'Authorization': ''
}
}

request(option)
    .then(response => {

})
.catch(error => {
})
```

What's wrong here? Please suggest.

Update - Response data. I am trying to get 'score'

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"ist":"json",
"version":"1.0"}},
"response":{"score":2,"start":0,"maxScore":18.9204}
}
```

Comment: What property of the response are you trying to access?

Comment: Can you post your response which you are getting in then block and which properties are not accessible?

Comment: @KrinaSoni i have updated the post with response data.pls see

Comment: @OTZ  i have updated the post with response data.pls see

Answer (score 0):

Your response has itself a property called response. To access your score value you would need to call `response.response.score`.

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "response": {
    "score": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 18.9204
  }
}
```

This is your response and you can access as below.

```
request(option)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.response.score)
})
.catch(error => {
})
```